# Scope of input haskell

Tags: haskell, input, io, program-entry-point

I'm having trouble taking in an input. Running it through functions. And outputting it. I have tried to do this in 2 different ways but neither work. Looking around online I see everyone only using the variable of the input inside the main. This would explain why I'm getting a "not in scope" error. But how would this be possible? Here are my two attempts.

```
result = lcm 3 inp

main = do
   inp <- getLine
   putStr result
```

and this:

```
main = do
   inp <- getLine
   putStr result
      where
      result = lcm 3 inp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inp` exists only within the scope of the `do` expression, which explains why you get an error in the first version.

As for the second version. it can be rewritten to:

```
main = e
  where
    e = do
        inp <- getLine
        putStr result
    result = lcm 3 inp
```

The two `where` bindings have different scopes, which is why a local binding from one expression is inaccessible from the other.

This, on the other hand, should work:

```
main = do
  inp <- getLine
  let result = lcm 3 inp
  putStr result
```

`result` is now defined within the `do` notation scope, so it can use `inp`. If you still want to use the `where` clause, `result` will need to accept `inp` as an argument:

```
main = do
  inp <- getLine
  putStr result
  where     
    result inp = lcm 3 inp
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the types of the things you use:

```
*Main> :t lcm
lcm :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
*Main> let result inp = lcm 3 inp
*Main> :t result
result :: Integral a => a -> a
```

But you read in a String:

```
*Main> :t getLine
getLine :: IO String
```

So, you need to convert a String to something like an integer, and convert an Inegral the `result` returned back to Striing for printing.

```
main = do
    inp <- getLine
    putStr $ show $ result (read inp)
```